# Codeigniter using forms for each row of the table to pass id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a data table that I want to edit. I currently pass the id via the url to an edit page and provide a form that loads details from the database. However if there is any validation error, the form will reset and the details will disappear. I am thinking that if each row were a form, I could post the data and even with a refresh, the id would still remain. However I am afraid how slow it would make my table. 
Does anyone have any other method that I may use? Thank you.

This is my code

View

```
<?php if($edit == "false"){
        echo form_open_multipart('Control/Products/ProductDetail/addProduct','class="productdetail"');
 }else{
        echo form_open_multipart('Control/Products/ProductDetail/editProduct','class="productdetail"');
       }?>
                            <label for="inputproductname">Product Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputproductname" name="inputproductname" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                            <label for="inputproductdescription">Product Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputproductdescription" name="inputproductdescription" placeholder="Description" rows="7" 
                            ><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
                            <label for="inputproductprice">Product Price</label>
                            <input type="price" class="form-control" id="inputproductprice" name="inputproductprice" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                            <label for="inputproductimage">Product Image</label>
                            <p><input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="upload" id="upload" aria-describedby="fileHelp"></p>
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="inputcurrentid" name="inputcurrentid" value="<?php echo $currentid; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="inputcurrentstatus" name="inputcurrentstatus" value="<?php echo $currentstatus; ?>">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                     <?php if($edit == "false"){
                         echo "Add";
                      }else{
                          echo "Edit";
                      }?>
             </button>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Control/Products/Products">Cancel</a>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('Form'); ?></p>
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
      $productid = $this->uri->segment(5);
      $editstatus = $this->uri->segment(6);
      if($editstatus == "false"){
          $data['name'] = '';
          $data['description'] = '';
          $data['price'] = '';
          $data['edit'] = "false";
          $data['message']='';
          $data['currentid'] = '';
          $data['currentstatus'] = '';
      }else{
          $product = $this->ProductsModel->getProduct($productid);
          foreach ($product as $productdetail){
            $data['name'] = $productdetail->name;
            $data['description'] = $productdetail->description;
            $data['price'] = $productdetail->price;
          }
          $data['edit'] = "true";
          $data['message']='';
          $data['currentid'] = $productid;
          $data['currentstatus'] = $editstatus;
      }
      $this->load->view('control/controlMenu/navigationLink');
      $this->load->view('control/controlProducts/productDetail',$data);
      $this->load->view('control/controlMenu/navigationJquery');
    }

public function editProduct(){
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductname', 'Name', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductdescription', 'Description', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductprice', 'Price', 'trim|required');
      if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
      {
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('upload', 'Image', 'required');
      }

      $inputproductname = $this->input->post('inputproductname');
      $inputproductdescription = $this->input->post('inputproductdescription');
      $inputproductprice = $this->input->post('inputproductprice');
      $inputdateadded = date('Y-m-d');
      $inputcurrentid = $this->input->post('inputcurrentid');
      $inputcurrentstatus = $this->input->post('inputcurrentstatus');

      $config['upload_path'] = $this->getProductImageFolderPath();
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png'; 
      $config['max_size'] = 3000;  
      $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
      $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
      $config['file_name'] = $inputproductname;
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);


      if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
          redirect('/Control/Products/ProductDetail/index/'.$inputcurrentid.'/'.$inputcurrentstatus);
        }else{
          if(!$this->upload->do_upload('upload')){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('Form',$this->upload->display_errors());
            redirect('Control/'.$this->getCurrentModule().'/'.$this->getClassName());
          }else{
              $extension = $this->upload->data('file_ext');
              $productdetails = array(
                'name'=>$inputproductname,
                'description'=>$inputproductdescription,
                'price'=>$inputproductprice,
                'imagePath'=>$config['upload_path'].$config['file_name'].$extension,
                'dateAdded'=>$inputdateadded
              );
              $this->db->trans_start();
              $this->ProductsModel->editProduct($productid,$productdetails);
              $this->db->trans_complete();
              if($this->db->trans_status()===false){

              }else{
                  $this->session->set_flashdata('Form', $inputproductname . ' has been altered on the database');
                  redirect('/Control/Products/Products');
              }
          }
        }
  }
```

Comment: If you are using GET method even you refresh a page the query string still in the url

Comment: The problem is I used to use $this->index and that would remove my query strings

Comment: where did you used it?

Comment: Where my redirect is at the moment. The problem with what I've placed is that the form validations do not activate

Comment: Try to use ajax or you can segregate your methods into one method and use conditions for generating results so that even if you use only one view you can view the results

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by segregating my methods into one method? And how will I use ajax? I am quite unfamiliar with how I can implement this as I won't be able to get the query string from the url once it goes to $this->index

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is, you make different method to add and edit or you can use ajax to call data and setInterval function to manage time you get the data

Comment: At the moment they have different methods to add and edit. However they share the same view

Comment: ough, so you must try use ajax and setInterval on javascript